# AS3 Array sorting issue

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, sorting

I have had a break of AS3 for a while and I'm rusty to say the least.

I would like my array to be sorted in size order (smallest to biggest).

this is my code

```
    public function sort_by_value():void
    {
        var tmp_array:Array = new Array();
        var counter:Number = 1;

        for each (var hand_card:Number in TABLE.CARDS_IN_PLAYER_1_HAND)
        {
            tmp_array.push(hand_card);
            trace(hand_card)
            counter++;
        }

        tmp_array.sortOn(Array.DESCENDING);
         trace(tmp_array);
    }
```

This is the output.

```
34
40
51
30
8
27
14
52
36
19
50
33
9

14,40,51,30,8,27,34,52,36,19,50,33,9
```

Why isn't it sorting corrently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `sortOn` is used to sort objects by a property ([documentation link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fa4.html)).

> `sortOn()` Allows you to sort objects that have one or more common properties, specifying the property or properties to use as the sort keys

Use `sort` instead.

> `sort()` Allows you to sort the Array’s elements in a variety of predefined ways, such as alphabetical or numeric order. You can also specify a custom sorting algorithm.

You will also want to use the `Array.NUMERIC` flag.

### Example:

```
tmp_array.sort(Array.DESCENDING | Array.NUMERIC);
```